# Removing root element above an array for json output in wso2. Please guide(2)

Tags: xslt, wso2, wso2-esb

Respected Sir,

I have output like below from my xslt :

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soapenv:Body>
        <Result>
            <Detail>
                <a>40</a>
                <b>car</b>
                <c>2019-01-17T00:00:00</c>
            </Detail>
            <Detail>
                <a>37</a>
                <b>table</b>
                <c>2019-01-17T00:00:00</c>
            </Detail>
            <Detail>
                <a>35</a>
                <b>book</b>
                <c>2019-01-17T00:00:00</c>
            </Detail>
            <Detail>
                <a>26</a>
                <b>box</b>
                <c>2019-01-17T00:00:00</c>
            </Detail>
        </Result>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

which gets converted into below json in postman :

```
{
    "Result": {
        "Detail": [
            {
                "a": "40",
                "b": "car",
                "c": "2019-01-17T00:00:00"
            },
            {
                "a": "37",
                "b": "table",
                "c": "2019-01-17T00:00:00"
            },
            {
                "a": "35",
                "b": "book",
                "c": "2019-01-17T00:00:00"
            },
            {
                "a": "26",
                "b": "box",
                "c": "2019-01-17T00:00:00"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

but in my desired output response . I do not want root element "Result".

Desired output :

```
{
    "Detail": [
            {
                "a": "40",
                "b": "car",
                "c": "2019-01-17T00:00:00"
            },
            {
                "a": "37",
                "b": "table",
                "c": "2019-01-17T00:00:00"
            },
            {
                "a": "35",
                "b": "book",
                "c": "2019-01-17T00:00:00"
            },
            {
                "a": "26",
                "b": "box",
                "c": "2019-01-17T00:00:00"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Going through some online documents I tried below enrich after xslt.

```
<enrich>
        <source clone="true" xpath="$body/Result/Detail"/>
        <target type="body"/>
</enrich>
```

But it gives only one element from my output  like below :

```
{
    "Detail": {
        "a": "40",
        "b": "car",
        "c": "2019-01-17T00:00:00"
    }
}
```

Please guide.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Haven't tried if it works but I guess it should. Before you're send I'd try to execute the following xslt which will remove the "Result".

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:sf="urn:sobject.partner.soap.sforce.com">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
 <xsl:copy>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
 </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Column[@SourceColumn='Result']|Result" ><xsl:apply-templates select="*"/></xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Hope that helps.